# "safe-restore-to-time" not present in host status which is required for restore DB to a safe timestamp?

Tags: marklogic

I need to restore a DB to a safe timestamp. For that I executed below command to retrieve safe-restore-timestamp value from the host status -

```
let $hostStatus := xdmp:host-status(xdmp:hosts())
return $hostStatus/*:safe-restore-to-time
```

I could not see the element `safe-restore-to-time` anywhere in the XML configuration file.
Can someone explain about restoring the DB to a safe timestamp having journal archive enabled ?

Answer (score 2):

Just answering this in case someone stumbles across on this.

```
let $safeTime :=  xdmp:host-status(xdmp:host("host_name"))/host:restore-jobs/host:restore-job/host:safe-restore-to-time
return $safeTime
```

The manual link is -
[Restoring DB to the Safe Timestamp](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/backup_restore#id_74555)